# How to prevent all project from attack, seems like spring didn't protect all site

Tags: java, spring-mvc

spring security

I have to prevent some attack (Xss , Xframe ,X-Content)

But the resault from owasp zap , It seems like it just pretect the `jsp` file  ,not all project

for example, these site under `WebContent`  still can't prevent attack

```
http://localhost:8080/My_Project/javascript/login.js
http://localhost:8080/My_Project/javascript/manager.js
http://localhost:8080/My_Project/ui/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

How can I do to protect my web site ?

Here is my method now:

Add the `SecurityHeadersInterceptor.java`

```
public class SecurityHeadersInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

      @Override
      public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
          response.setHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
          response.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
          response.setHeader("X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block");
          super.postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);
      }
    }
```

and use interceptors

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
    <bean class="com.my.project.interceptor.SecurityHeadersInterceptor"/>
    </mvc:interceptor>   
</mvc:interceptors>
```